# Not able to sign my Android app anymore, as I keep getting "Cannot recover key"

Tags: android, android-studio

Having uploaded to play lots of times without problems I now see "Cannot recover key" when trying to sign my app. I sign my app the normal way:

[Generate sig....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iixTu.png)

The passwords are correct as I have tested it using them in:

[Keytool -list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv1qh.png)

and found them in
E:\Android\MyLocations\app\build\intermediates\signing_config\release\out\signing-config.json

But I keep getting "Cannot recover key"

Both passwords are the same.

I have the private_key.pepk file if that helps.

I can sign debug versions without any problems. Using another jks file of course.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after I upgraded to Android Studio 3.5 this is how I resolved it.

1. I went the Google Play console > app name > release management > app
   signing.
2. At the very bottom of that page is a link to reset your
   upload key. Fill in the form and wait for Google to reply to you.
3. I
   received a reply after 12 days.

[image: Email response from google play developer support]

Answer (score -2):

What I did was edit the file E:\Android\MyLocations\app\build\intermediates\signing_config\ release\out\signing-config.json through a notepad, and replace the correct keys, and this is how I it worked.